# how to link a jquery file in global.config.php?

Tags: php, jquery

Actually i am writting a php script to link some javascript files in my multiple sites.

> Example : site_dir1/js/jquery.1.4.2.js and
>   site_dir2/js/jquery.1.4.2.js

In this case, in the document_root location i have a file called "jquery/jquery.inc.php which has the follwing code

```
$jq_142 = "<script type='text/javascript' language='JavaScript' src='jquery-1.4.2.min.js'></script>";
```

I will use this code to make require my php file anywhere i want

```
<?php require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/jquery/jquery.inc.php' ?>
```

And the reputation of jquery file keeps only one copy in my following location.

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/jquery'
```

My doubt is still my javascript files are not loaded where ever i call the files.

I am little messed. how to fix it? any better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to do this you need to give the script an absolute path rather than a relative one.

When you include it in `index.php`, the browser will look at `/jquery.js` for the file. When you include it in `/folder/page.php`, the browser will look check `/folder/jquery.js`.

See how it changes depending on where you are in the website? You need to tell it to look at a specific place, like:

`$jq_142 = "<script type='text/javascript' language='JavaScript' src='http://example.com/scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js'></script>";`

This means that no matter where you are in your site, the browser will check `http://example.com/scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js` for jQuery.

Comment: Thank you!  Yes My jquery.js file is already in a the folder you meant. And, the problem i found is how my variable $jq_142 in jquery.inc.php isn't called in any other php script in a site folder.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found my **page.php** script have loaded my **jquery.inc.php** file. But the jquery file linking script has been coded inside quotes as follow :

```
 $jq_142 = "<script type='text/javascript' language='JavaScript' src='jquery-1.4.2.min.js'></script>";
```

So it's couldn't be displayed. And i found this jquery.inc.php is not called by **.html** files. Only for **.php** files. I couldn't find any alternative solution for this problem.

I have linked by using the absolute path of my unreplicated jquery library files from **jquery/jquery-xxx.js** directly.